# Addition and Subtraction between two data originated from different data set

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset "A" where I found a column named "A1" (Data Type 'nvarchar') and dataset "B" where I found a column "B1" (Data Type 'nvarchar') in SSRS. Now I want a column that will generate the difference between this two columns.
I have attempted the following three(03) as expressions.

1. `=First((Convert.ToInt32(Fields!A1.Value, "A"))) - First((Convert.ToInt32(Fields!B1.Value, "B")))`
2. `=First(Fields!A1.Value, "A") - First(Fields!B1.Value, "B")`
3. `=(Fields!A1.Value, "A") - (Fields!B1.Value, "B")`

But I have found 0.00 for the number 2, But for 1 and 3 I can not go for preview as for error.

What could be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for my problem. I have taken two more columns in each dataset to compare using lookup functions.
Now,
In dataset 'A' there are two data one is 'A1'(Previous One) and 'A2'(new).
In dataset 'B' there are two data one is 'B1'(Previous One) and 'B2'(new).
Now I have written the following in expressions:

```
=VAL(FIRST(Fields!A1.Value, "A")) - Lookup(Fields!A2.Value, Fields!B2.Value, Fields!B1.Value, "B")
```

Let me know if any other way found for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=VAL(FIRST(Fields!A1.Value, "A")) - VAL(FIRST(Fields!B1.Value, "B"))
```

This simply gets the first value from each dataset, then converts it to a numeric value before doing the subtraction.

`VAL()` to ignore any spaces etc in the string you are converting so is sometime more reliable than other methods.

If this does not help, please share samples of the datasets, including any special characters or spaces that may be present.

Comment: I have tried this approach. But it doesn't work.